# Cannot resolve method 'authenticated' in 'RequestMatcherConfigurer'

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement token revoke using Spring OAuth2. I created this endpoint:

```
    @PostMapping("/oauth/revoke")
    public ResponseEntity<String> revoke(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
        RevocationService revocationService = revocationServiceFactory
                .create(params.get("token_type_hint"));

        revocationService.revoke(params.get("token"));

        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

Github [code](https://github.com/rcbandit111/OAuth2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/rest/TokenRevocationController.java#L23)

I tried to configure these permissions:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()

            .requestMatchers().anyRequest().authenticated().and()      //<-- Error here
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/revoke").permitAll().and()
            .httpBasic().and()

            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

}
```

I can successfully generate OAuth2 token but I get always `Access denied` usisng this request:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/revoke' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46cXdlcnR5' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'token=.......' \
--data-urlencode 'token_type_hint=access_token'
```

Do you know how path `/oauth/revoke` should be properly configured to allow authenticated users only to use this path? I get error `Cannot resolve method 'authenticated' in 'RequestMatcherConfigurer'` when I tied to apply the above configuration

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess. You are mixing Spring versions from 5 to 1.2, you are mixing incompatible Spring Cloud versions etc. The fact that your dependencies are a mess, is the reason you get this error.

Comment: OK, I agree. I will set `spring-cloud-starter-parent` for dependency management. Anything lease that I need to change?